# Is it acceptable style to have a constructor block?

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop

Concrete Example: Abstraction of a controlling unit, which could also be a remote unit represented by a socket. For ease of use, I consider creating the sockets and accept()'ing already in the constructor.

However, this feels slightly weird. Such a constructor could always fail. And it could block. Is there a way that doesn't make me uncomfortable, or is it just OO and I have to take that pill?

(This question relates especially to the trendy OO languages and the generally accepted styles used there)

Comment: please provide code to make your question more clear

Comment: Why does this question read like a markov chain?

Comment: @DavidB: Please explain. I think the question was asked in a straighforward way.

Comment: @Micah Armantrout: I could provide code, although to keep it short it could not be real code. The question is a general one (in the title), the network specialization is only for illustration.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes... +1 from me, which should compensate for the first -5...

Comment: @DavidRodriguez: Thanks, I feel better now :>

Comment: @JoSo: Actually it is interesting, because I believe that more libraries should behave in the way you are trying. It is not usual, as many libraries allow for objects to be created before they are accessible (`fstream`, for example) even though the set of operations on an open and a closed file are completely different and thus a closed file is only loosely related to an open file... but having a single type means that the type must offer the superset of operations (meaning that the compiler will be glad to allow multiple `open()` or trying to read from a closed file...)

Comment: @DavidRodriguez: Yes, such issues also bugged me in example code from my professors. It feels just slightly wrong in the face of also having constructors and destructors. Normally I'd like to assume that all member functions (not counting constructor/destructor) should share the same set of pre- and postconditions. At least I thought the general idea behind classes is to encapsulate state wherever sensibly possible.

Comment: @JoSo: Note that the problem is symmetric (and not trivial), that is, can you *close* the resource? What is the result of closing the resource? If you want to support early closing of a resource (i.e. before the end of the current scope) and the type only supports the operations for when it is open you might need to make a deeper redesign (i.e. dynamically allocate your object, and return a smart pointer of some kind) so that the multiple states can be handled externally (in the pointer). A `connection` is either open (and there is an object) or it is not and there is no object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is not necessarily bad to lock on a constructor, I would consider hiding that from the user. Something like:

```
connection establish_connection();
```

From user code, if they see:

```
connection c = establish_connection();
```

It seems sensible that a connection is established and the active connection is returned. Users expect the code to possibly fail (exception) or block, so there will be no surprises there, considering that in many libraries the creation of a `socket` is a non-blocking call.

Note: in this code `connection` represents an active connection, the library should control whether the `connection` can be *created* directly or not, whether it can be *closed* (by anything other than the destructor, i.e. whether a `connection` object can be alive and not represent an active connection) and whether it can be copied or not and what the semantics are.

Comment: +1. I'm accepting this one because it presents a solution making more intuitive code. I'll probably try to make my constructor private and have a static `establish_connection` member.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, the class template `std::lock_guard` will happily block until it acquires a lock on a mutex:

```
std::mutex m;

{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(m);

    //...
}
```

This is an entirely legitimate use, and strongly idiomatic C++ using the SBRM idiom ("scope-bound resource management", formerly known as "RAII").

Comment: Thank you, that's the sort of answer I wanted. Still waiting for more examples to come before accepting :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, constructors can block. The classic example is a class that represents an RAII mutex, acquiring the mutex on construction. That constructor will block until the other thread releases the mutex.

If your `accept` *fails* outright then you should throw an exception from the constructor to indicate such failure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Abstract Factory design pattern. You can hide concrete classes that inherit from their own interfaces, avoiding you to create an instance in the normal way. Then you create a class that have acess to the concrete classes and can build these objects for you, like a factory. For example:

In Your library:

```
//ConcreteWindow class must not be visible to the final user.
class ConcreteWindow : public AbstractWindow
{
    ...
};

class GUIManager
{
public:
    AbstractWindow* createWindow()
    {
        return new ConcreteWindow();
    }

    ...
};
```

In Your Application:

```
GUIManager* gui = new GUIManager();

//ConcreteWindow class not visible.
AbstractWindow* myWindow = gui->createWindow();
```

In C++ you don't have access modifier to classes, like Java and C#. But you can use namespaces or headers includes (not including), to hide the concrete classes. You are now forced to "ask" your factory class to create that object for you.